single quotes in string parameter in sql query override in Informatica developer client
I need to parameterize the query override used in source transformation in Informatica developer client 10.5, so I created a string parameter that will hold the query override.
The parameter query is like
SELECT /*+  PARALLEL(16) NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE*/ RECID, Q.* FROM 
F_POSTING_RESTRICT
  x, XMLTABLE ('/row' PASSING XMLRECORD COLUMNS 
  RESTRICTION_TYPE VARCHAR2 (6) PATH 'c2', DISPO_OFFICER VARCHAR2 (4) PATH 'c3'
  )Q

But when I execute run data viewer it fails as it add another quote to each single quote so it makes the query like:
SELECT /*+  PARALLEL(16) NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE*/ RECID, Q.* FROM 
F_POSTING_RESTRICT
  x, XMLTABLE (''/row'' PASSING XMLRECORD COLUMNS 
  RESTRICTION_TYPE VARCHAR2 (6) PATH ''c2'', DISPO_OFFICER VARCHAR2 (4) PATH ''c3''
  )Q

I have tried CHR(39) but it didn't work as it is copied to the query as it is.

did you set the parameter as parameter and type = string (4000) ? And also can you pls put the whole SQL in one single line and try ?

Yes it is string type parameter, and i have tried to make it in single line but still gets the same issue
